# Exchange Impersonation Permissions - Subfolders not visible

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

We have an issue using powershell and exchange impersonation permissions. The login to several mailboxes works correctly however, when a mailbox has subfolders created by the user, the folders will not be visibile. Once i grant fullmailbox access and remove the impersonation permissions, the subfolders are visible and the search criteria works fine.

Is there a limitation in exchange impersonation permissions which doesn't allow to see/enumerate Mailbox subfolders created by the user itself?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Subfolders within a mailbox are invisble

Comment: That's just a statement, and a vague one at best - multiple questions could lead from this: "Why is subfolders invisible to certain delegates?", "Can this behavior be changed without granting full mailbox access to a delegate?", "*How* would I change this behavior". You'll probably need to provide more details though, if you want qualified answers to any of those.